# Custom Actionbar font

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textview, typeface

I am looking to customize my action-bar Main Activity title font I have researched alot and tried almost everything out there but i still can seem to get my font to change I have all the fonts i wish to use imported into eclipse as well. I CAN set a basic textview to the font as a test but not the actionbar here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    day = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
    ttime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.track);

    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("ActivivtyName");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("DAEMONES.TTF"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

Comment: Have you tried [styling](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) the action bar as stated in the reference? You can apply your custom font there

Comment: @spezzino No you can't apply custom fonts with styles.

Comment: @spezzino not sure what you mean so probably not can you give me an example to try?

Comment: Does the custom font not get applied to the Spannable at all when setting as a ActionBar Title?

Comment: @Ahmad No nothing happens